# Creating lists from a string, separating words from numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Say I have a string that contains numbers and words, such as this one:

```
string = "there are 1234 words and numbers 5678 in here $999";
```

How would I separate the string into an ordered list containing sublists populated with words and numbers? The ideal list would look like this:

```
idealList = {{there are}, {1234}, {words and numbers}, {5678}, {in here}, {$999}}
```

I know how to extract all words and all numbers, but I can't create a list like the previous one.

---

Here's an example of what I tried to extract words and its output:

```
StringCases[string, RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]]
{there, are, words, and, numbers, in, here}
```

I can also do this with pattern-matching instead of RegEx, but it doesn't get me closer to my goal.

Is my regex simply wrong, or does this problem require a tiny bit more involved solution?

Comment: In my view using regular expression is not good, in the sense that use of regular expression degrades the performance, it take more time.

Comment: @gaurab: in the absence of concrete evidence (e.g. timing results) to back up your claim, your words are far from being an answer. I have thus turned your "answer" into a comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about this?

```
StringSplit[string, i : NumberString :> i]
```

Ok, everyone's giving answers that actually work with the `$`, so here's an edit, as @kguler and @MrWizard suggested

```
StringSplit[string, i : ("" | "$" ~~ NumberString) :> i] // StringTrim
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain how it works please?

Comment: @CHM, it splits the strings where it finds a `NumberString`, keeping the `NumberString`

Comment: You can also modify the pattern to use `Alternatives` as in `StringSplit[string, i : NumberString | StringExpression["$" ~~ NumberString] :> i]` or, `StringSplit[string, i : NumberString | ("$" ~~ NumberString) :> i]` (+1).

Comment: +1 -- however, I think you shouldn't need `StringTrim` after using `StringSplit[string]`.

Comment: @kguler, I edited. I had first tried that but fast and was bitten by ~~ vs |'s precedence and didn't spend a second realising that was the issue

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you're right, Riffle only puts stuff in between

Comment: Yes, but after your edit you need `StringTrim` again! :^)  Try this: `StringSplit[string, i : ("" | "$" ~~ NumberString) :> i] // StringTrim`

Comment: Wanna go to work in my place today @MrWizard? It's not my day :)

Comment: @Rojo lol -- not if you want a job to return to. =:-O

Answer (score 6):

Note that Rojo's solution splits the expression containing the dollar sign as well:

```
StringSplit["there are 1234 words and numbers 5678 in here $999", i : NumberString :> i]
{"there are ", "1234", " words and numbers ", "5678", " in here $", "999"}
```

If you don't want that splitting to happen, here's one way, using a regex:

```
StringSplit["there are 1234 words and numbers 5678 in here $999",
            s : RegularExpression[".(\\d+)."] :> s]
{"there are", " 1234 ", "words and numbers", " 5678 ", "in here ", "$999"}
```

If the spaces in the ends of the strings are bothersome, you can use `StringTrim[]` to get rid of them:

```
StringSplit["there are 1234 words and numbers 5678 in here $999",
            s : RegularExpression[".(\\d+)."] :> s] // StringTrim
{"there are", "1234", "words and numbers", "5678", "in here", "$999"}
```

---

As another example:

```
str1 = "At 50x magnification, they'd better be paying me $1080 in 9 installments!";

StringSplit[str1, s : RegularExpression[".(\\d+)."] :> s] // StringTrim
{"At", "50x", "magnification, they'd better be paying me", "$1080", "in",
 "9", "installments!"}
```

The other methods presented would perform a splitting like

```
{"At", "50", "x magnification, they'd better be paying me", "$1080", "in",
 "9", "installments!"}
```

which may or may not be the desired behavior...

Comment: One could of course use a `StringExpression[]` instead of a `RegularExpression[]`: `s : (_ ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ _) :> s`.

Comment: `StringSplit["there are 1234 words and numbers 5678 in here $999", 
  RegularExpression["\\$?(\\d)+"] -> "$0"] // StringTrim`a little bit more compact

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the solutions given by Rojo and J.M. to the following one. But if you want to see a working version of your original approach with `StringCases` and `RegularExpression`, here is one possibility

```
StringCases[string, RegularExpression["([A-Za-z]|\\s)+|(\\$|\\d)+"]]
```

It returns

```
{"there are ", "1234", " words and numbers ", "5678", " in here ","$999"}
```

and as J.M. suggests above, apply `StringTrim` if desired. Handling decimals could also easily be added.

Comment: Instead of the pattern `[A-Za-z]` in the regex, you could use `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: Ah nice, I couldn't think of a more proper RegEx. Only ick is that there are spaces before and after " words and numbers ".

Answer (score 3):

Further variations:

using `StringReplace`:

```
List @@ StringTrim /@ StringReplace[string, 
    a : Except[{"$", DigitCharacter}] .. | NumberString | ("$" ~~ NumberString) :> {a}]
```

or, using the same replacement rule in `StringCases`:

```
 StringTrim /@ StringCases[string, 
   a : Except[{"$", DigitCharacter}] .. | NumberString | ("$" ~~ NumberString) :> {a}]
```

both yield:

[image]